# Quote a command for `find -execdir test [command]` (Bash)

Tags: bash, find

I would like to execute following command to do `git fetch` in git repos if the have a remote (= `git remote` is non-empty):

```
find -name .git -execdir test $(git remote) \; -execdir git fetch
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              How to quote/escape/mask this?
```

Tried much variations which don't work like: `"$(git remote)"`, `'$(git remote)'`, `\$\(git remote\)`, `'"$(git remote)'"`, ...

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question you asked, but you can also use a glob: `shopt -s globstar; for d in **/*.git; do pushd "$d"; test ...; popd; done`

Comment: @slhck Also a nice idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find -name .git -execdir sh -c 'test $(git remote)' \; -execdir git fetch \;
```

and because that starts a shell anyway, you can even do:

```
find -name .git -execdir sh -c 'test $(git remote) && git fetch' \;
```